# Problem after auto-mount using pysdm

Tags: boot, automount, reboot

I wanted to auto-mount my ntfs drives on boot time, so I went through this article to do so using ***pysdm***.

I followed this article    [auto-mount-your-ntfs-partition-in-ubuntu](http://maketecheasier.com/auto-mount-your-ntfs-partition-in-ubuntu/2009/04/14).

1. But when I tried to uncheck the box Mount file system in read only mode, It didn't work. It was checked again, on its own. The drives were also mounted not by the user names, but by the names sda3, sda5 etc.
2. In the option for the specifying the name for the ntfs drives, i specified my own names, the names by which the drives were usually mounted.

I didn't try to uninstall the package, as I thought that might be harmful and could be fatal.

**Now, when I restarted my Ubuntu, it just doesn't restart.**
It stays in an infinite loop, i guess and even the login screen doesn't showup.

Please help me, and if something is not clear in the question, let me know. Suggest any possible way, I can get my Ubuntu (10.04) back and running, with my packages as they were configured.

**EDITED:** I ran Ubuntu in the recovery mode, and it showed the following output on the console twice and then went off to the same ubuntu logo as earlier on.

```
fcsk from util-linux-ng 2.17.2
/dev/sda8: clean, 635759/1152816 files, 2954346/4605952 blocks
mount: unknown filesystem type 'Spoon'
mountall: mount /media/Silver[782] terminated with status 32
mountall: Filesystem could not be mounted: /media/Silver
init: ureadahead-other main process (893) terminated with status 4
init: ureadahead-other main process (906) terminated with status 4
init: ureadahead-other main process (917) terminated with status 4
```

The error that I can see is that I incidently typed the mount location of a drive to **/sda/Silver Spoon** and that is causing trouble.

Comment: You might want to boot into recovery mode (not that I know how to bring up the GRUB menu). And in future, I recommend manually editing the `fstab` file to mount partitions.

Comment: Boot into a Ubuntu LiveCD/USB, mount your Ubuntu partition (on the hard disk), and copy the contents of the `/etc/fstab` file here.

Comment: install ntfs-config and try from it.

Comment: @Oxwivi: I tried booting into recovery mode and it showed the above output and then again the same ubuntu logo and nothing at all like before.

Comment: @arrange: I am not familiar with this stuff very well, i mean mount ypur Ubuntu partition on the hard disk. Can you guide me how to do that.

Comment: @sagarchalise: How can I install ntfs-config while I can't even make it to login screen?

Comment: @Jatin Oh, boot from livecd/usb and mount your hard drive, you can do it with places or gparted or gnome-disk-utilty. Go to /etc/fstab on your mounted partition and comment the line with /dev/sda8 and then try rebooting.

Comment: @sagarchalise: Thanks. It worked. However I am stuck with another problem [ Ubuntu auto-mounts ntfs drives in Read-Only Mode](http://askubuntu.com/q/31634/12752). Can you help me here as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. With help from `@sagarchalise` and from this question
[problem-after-auto-mount-ntfs-drives-using-pysdm](https://superuser.com/q/260273/70791).